# HTTP 404 Error invoking servlet from netbeans maven project

Tags: maven, jsp, servlets, netbeans

Im having an error invoking a simple servlet in a maven project.
I've created a maven project from command line, with this line

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=my.group.id -DartifactId=MavenWebApp1  
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp 
-DinteractiveMode=false
```

after that I've imported it to netbeans, and add a simple servlet.
I invoke it from my JSP page and I get this error on the browser.

> **HTTP Status 404** - /newServlet
>       type Status report
>       message /newServlet
>       description The requested resource is not available.
>       Apache Tomcat/7.0.56

This is the JSP/HTML code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
        <form action="newServlet" method="POST">
            <input type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After that I've created a new Maven Java Web project from the Netbeans menu and I have the same error.
Finally I've created a new Java Web project (not maven) and it works ok!
Need I to make some changes to the maven project?

Thanks in advance for you help
Regards
Darío

Answer (score 0):

It´s solved, a few days later I created a new maven project on Netbeans and it's work correctly with servlets